# True or false questions (probability)

Tags: probability

A test has $2N$ True(T) or False(F) type of questions. For $N$ questions T is the correct answer and for the remaining $N$ questions F is the correct answer. Let's say a student is this test and he answers these questions randomly. The number of correct answers that he gets is $k$ where $(0 \leq k \leq 2N)$. $P_{k}$ is the probability of getting exactly $k$ correct answers.

(1) If $N=3$ what will $P_{k}$ be?$(k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6)$

(2) What's the general case for $P_{k}$ ?

This is what I tried to do:

(1) The probability of getting the right answer for a single question is $\frac{1}{2}$ and $2N=6$. Therefore,

$$P_{k}=_{6}\textrm{C}_{k}\left (  \frac{1}{2}\right )^{6}$$

(2) Using the same logic I get

$$P_{k}=_{2N}\textrm{C}_{k}\left (  \frac{1}{2}\right )^{2N}$$

However, the correct answer for (2) seems to be $$P_{k}=\frac{\left ( _{N}\textrm{C}_{k} \right )^{2}}{_{2N}\textrm{C}_{N}}$$

I do not understand what's wrong with the way I approached this problem. Any advice?

$\textbf{EDIT}$

The answer $$P_{k}=\frac{\left ( _{N}\textrm{C}_{k} \right )^{2}}{_{2N}\textrm{C}_{N}}$$ does not seem to be correct. I got it from a 3rd party source, so I could not verify whether It was good or not.

In this particular case which I have described, the answer that I provided is actually correct.

Comment: Hmm... Since $k$ is how the number of questions answered correctly, is $P_k$ the probability of getting exactly $k$ correct answers? (It sounds a bit unclear in your question). Also, you might want to check out [binomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Definitions) if you haven't already 

Comment: Yes,  $P_{k}$ is the probability of getting exactly $k$ correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the student supposedly doesn't know which are the answers to be marked true, and which false, and is answering randomly, I can't see why the generalised answer for $2N$ questions should not be $P_k= \binom{2n}{k}(\frac12)^{2N}$

The book answer makes no sense to me !

Comment: Actually this is a question from a university entrance exam around 17 years ago. The answers were never released but I got this answer from another internet forum, so it might not be 100% accurate. Now I know that at least in this case my answer is correct.